# Full text search in mysql not giving what I want

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have implemented full text search on two fields (title, description)

now if I search for chelsea in it gives me right result but when i search for Manchester city then it give all the result where title/description contains manchester or city

ex Manchester city gives me result
manchester united
hull city
conventry city
etc

below is my query

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM news WHERE MATCH (title, description) AGAINST (:search)
```

Comment: Have you added `Fulltext index` on these two columns ?

Comment: yes, its working fine with one key word, if words have space then it individually searches the words and give a mixed result

Comment: yes.. the result is coming ok, just when two words come it displays result on individual basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to add Fulltext index see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) and then write something like:

> SELECT * FROM patient_db WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number ) AGAINST ('+first_word +second_word +third_word' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Comment: i think you didnt got the q

Comment: its aready added and working fine. but with 2 words seperated by space it is giving result for either of the words, I want the result where both words match instead of each single

Comment: Mm, I see, I have used SELECT * FROM patient_db WHERE MATCH ( Name, id_number ) AGAINST ('+first_word +second_word +third_word' IN BOOLEAN MODE); and worked fine